# Cordova inAppBrowser how to hide URL and show the done button only

Tags: jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

How I can hide the url from inAppBrowser but I need to show the Done button so the user is able to close the inAppBrowser windows and return to app?

I've tried modifying the inAppBrowser.java to show the button only and rebuilded the app but still the toolbar is showing the Back/Forward buttons,Url and Done button.

```
// Add the views to our toolbar
                //toolbar.addView(actionButtonContainer); removed URL location
                //toolbar.addView(edittext); removed URL  
                toolbar.addView(close); // Show Done only

                // Don't add the toolbar if its been disabled
                if (getShowLocationBar()) {
                    // Add our toolbar to our main view/layout
                    main.addView(toolbar);
                }
```

As I saw from one stackoverflow answer the 2nd and 3rd commented lines in the code above should hide the back/forward buttons and the url.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be able to use the standard InAppBrowser options to hide the toolbar (Back / Forward), URL (location) and DONE should be displayed by default / option to return depending on device.

```
window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://url_to_open.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes')
```